# Add active class to a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small issue with this code,

```
jQuery('.nav-menu  li:has(a[href="'+ window.location.pathname +'"])').addClass('active');
```

It gives me results like this:

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="/someUrl">Test</a>
 </li>
```

But I want something like this:

```
 <li>
  <a href="/someUrl" class="active">Test</a>
 </li>
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there . You need to [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) anchor tag before `addClass`.

```
jQuery('.nav-menu li:has(a[href="'+ window.location.pathname +'"])').find('a').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag after `li` in your selector.

```
jQuery('.nav-menu  li:has(a[href="'+ window.location.pathname +'"]) a').addClass('active');
```